# Sending data to another JSP file from action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, action, ognl

The main page has link to create new record and one to show all the existing records.

On the `create_new_record` page I am writing all the data to a file in an action class method called `saveRecords` and populating a `List<Records>` in `retriveRecords` methods.

**My action class code:**

```java
public class MyRecordes{
  List<RecoredInfo> recoreds= new ArrayList<RecoredInfo>();
}
```

I have getters and setters for the same `records` in my action class(I am using Struts 2),
but on the main page when I click to show all records (which shows a different JSP page), nothing is displayed. Do I have to use servlets and/or `doGet`, etc. methods?

### EDIT:

Adding code for `showList.jsp`:

```jasp
<table>         
<s:iterator value="arrayList" status="status">
<tr>
<td><s:property value="firstName"/> <s:property value="lastName"/>
</td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

My `Action` class has an arraylist named `arrayList` and I am using getters/setters to set the value.

Comment: Dont bother to share your code. I cant guess anything about your problem from your question. All things are mess up in your question.

Comment: you can make the `retrieveRecords` or other method return a string value, which will need to be the name of the other jsp page you wish to show the result in. so if the jsp page is named e.g. "records-list.jsp", the method can `return "record-list";` as long as you have linked the right beans in your xml file

Answer (score 0):

The different action will populate the list and return a result of the different JSP page. In the different JSP you can show `records` using

> [**`<iterator>`**](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/iterator-tag.html)
>
> Iterator will iterate over a value. An iterable value can be any of:
> `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.Iterator`, `java.util.Enumeration`,
> `java.util.Map`, or an array.

---

Whatever you show on the JSP the data should be bound to the beans properties that you can retrieve via OGNL expression and written to the JSP output.

> [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl)
>
> OGNL is the Object Graph Navigation Language (see
> [commons-ognl](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/) for the full
> documentation of OGNL). Here, we will cover a few examples of OGNL
> features that co-exist with the framework. To review basic concepts,
> refer to [OGNL Basics](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics).

---

If you are using Struts2 you don't need *servlets and/or `doGet` etc. methods*. Struts2 framework implements MVC pattern that you can follow while writing your web application. If you are new to the framework, then better get started from the Tutorials.

> [Tutorials](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/)
>
> The framework documentation is written for *active* web developers and
> assumes a working knowledge about how Java web applications are built.
> For more about the underlying nuts and bolts, see the [Key
> Technologies Primer](https://struts.apache.org/primer.html).

---

Comment: Hey thanks... can u look throught my code again please?

Comment: Your code looks like ok but you are missing other details.