# Struts 6.3.0.2 - Issue with ModelDriven and Form Submission

Tags: java, struts2, model-driven

```js
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        debugger;
        document.getElementById("AdvanceSettlementForm").submit();
        
    }
</script>
```

```html
<s:form method="post" name="AdvanceSettlementForm" action="orders"
                    cssClass="form-horizontal" theme="simple">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Settlement Voucher
                            Amount: <span class="mandatory">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <s:textfield maxlength="225" styleClass="form-control"
                                    name="settlementAmount" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                                <a
                                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/orders/saveSettlement"
                                    onclick=submitForm(); class="btn btn-default"> Save
                                    Settlement</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </s:form>
```

I'm facing an issue with Struts 2 6.3.0.2 while trying to implement `ModelDriven` with a form submission. I have an `AdvanceSettlementModel` and `AdvanceSettlementForm` where `AdvanceSettlementForm implements ModelDriven<AdvanceSettlementModel>`. However, when submitting the form, the model values are not getting populated in the action class.

I've verified that the form is being submitted, but the model in `AdvanceSettlementForm` is not getting populated with the submitted values. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

AdvanceSettlementModel:

```
public class AdvanceSettlementModel implements Serializable {
    private String settlementAmount;

    // Getters and setters for other properties
}
```

AdvanceSettlementForm:

```
public class AdvanceSettlementForm implements Serializable, ModelDriven<AdvanceSettlementModel> {
    private AdvanceSettlementModel model = new AdvanceSettlementModel();

    @Override
    public AdvanceSettlementModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    // Other properties and methods
}
```

struts.xml:

```
<package name="your-package" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="your-action" class="your-package.YourActionClass" method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
        <result>/your-result.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Controller:

```
public class YourActionClass extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<AdvanceSettlementForm> {
    private AdvanceSettlementForm form = new AdvanceSettlementForm();

    @Override
    public AdvanceSettlementForm getModel() {
        return form;
    }

    public String execute() {
        // Access model properties like form.getModel().getSettlementAmount()
        // However, values are not getting populated

        // Your business logic here

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Additionally, in my Struts action class, I noticed a method shouldRestrictToGET in the RestActionInvocation class:

```
// RestActionInvocation class
private boolean shouldRestrictToGET() {
    return !hasErrors
            && !"get".equalsIgnoreCase(ServletActionContext.getRequest().getMethod())
            && restrictToGet;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you submitting a form? Also you should already know that Struts 2 v.6.3.0.2 and all prior versions removed the concept of the  form bean used in the old Struts 1.x implementations. ModelDriven is not a replacement to form bean and also can be removed in the future versions because it doesn't replace the model in the Struts 2 MVC architecture. You should learn basics before dripping into trouble with Struts 2 misunderstanding [basic concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177210/573032).

Comment: I have added JSP above. I'm migrating struts 1.3 to 6.3.0.2 and using https://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts6302 documents and sample project.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with implementing `ModelDriven` interface. Only `Action` class should implement it. In this way you return a model bean with `getModel()`. Other form bean is obsolete.

```java
public class YourClassAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<AdvanceSettlementModel> {
    private AdvanceSettlementModel model = new AdvanceSettlementModel();

    @Override
    public AdvanceSettlementModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String execute() {
        // Access model properties like model.getSettlementAmount()
        

        // Your business logic here

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

---

You should also remove reference to `modelDriven` interceptor. Because you have overridden Struts default interceptors configuration for the action. In this way the `defaultStack` won't be configured. You can check a runtime configuration for you action to see which interceptors are configured.

```xml
<package name="your-package" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="your-action" class="yourpackage.YourClassAction">        
        <result>/your-result.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

---

In the JSP you can use

```xml
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("AdvanceSettlementForm").submit();
        
    }
</script>
<s:form method="post" id="AdvanceSettlementForm" action="your-action">
You can use JavaScript `submit()` function or 

<s:submit/>
<s:form/>
```

---

[How to use struts2 submit tag as button without submitting the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20217387/573032) is the reference how you can use `<s:submit>` using a JavaScript function.